# Migration from Xcode 10.3 to Xcode 11+ breaks call from overridden function in iOS Charts?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-charts

I'm currently using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) with CocoaPods and I have an issue that I don't quite understand.

I created a subclass of `PieChartView` and overwrote the function `calcMinMax` from `PieChartView` in my custom class, allowing me elsewhere to create a custom pie chart of my data.

I've changed the function in `PieChartView` from `internal override func calcMinMax()` to `open override func calcMinMax()`, allowing me to override it in my custom class using `public override func calcMinMax()`:

```
open class PieChartView: PieRadarChartViewBase
{
...
    open override func calcMinMax()
    {
        calcAngles()
    }
}

public class CustomPieChartView: PieChartView
{
....
    public override func calcMinMax()
    {
        calcAngles()
    }
}
```

In the demo application, I changed the chartView's type from `PieChartView` to `CustomPieChartView`, as well as updated the class type appropriately in `PieChartViewController.xib`:

```
class PieChartViewController: DemoBaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet var chartView: CustomPieChartView!

    ...
}
```

In Xcode 10.3, when the pie chart is about to be displayed, `notifyDataSetChanged` is called within the class `PieRadarCharViewBase`, which calls `calcMinMax`, and as a result calls the overridden `calcMinMax` in my custom class `CustomPieChartView`. **This works as expected.**

FYI: `PieChartView` is a subclass of `PieRadarCharViewBase`.

The stack is shown in Xcode 10.3 working correctly:

[image]

The **problem** is, migrating to Xcode 11, **without** updating any code breaks this functionality, and instead of calling `CustomPieChartView::calcMinMax`, calls the parent class `PieChartView::calcMinMax`, leading to a crash (irrelevant to the original issue).

The stack is shown in Xcode 11 working **incorrectly**:

[image]

I've attached the demo app containing the issue to better visualize and replicate my issue.

I simply cannot figure out what is causing this issue. I've tried to raise an issue in the library's repo, but have not received any responses: [drawAngles[j] crash in PieChartRenderer using custom PieChartView in Xcode 11+](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4231)

Does anyone know what is causing this, after running my demo app? [demo app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mv3sbxqghfj7zw5/Charts-master.zip?dl=0)

It's best to run the demo using Xcode 10.3 and Xcode 11 to see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you started changing access levels for classes members in the iOS-Chart library, but not deep enough. You have changed access level for function `calcMinMax()` in `PieChartView` class from `internal` to `open`. But you have not changed access level for the same function in `PieRadarChartViewBase` class and so on. Actually, you have to change access levels of `calcMinMax()` function throughout the class hierarchy.

Comment: Confirmed working!..Will award bounty when time expires